# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: completionKey

Tags: java, derby

When I'm trying to start my Derby Network Server, I'm getting this exception. This has never happened before and I don't now what's the cause of problem. Any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: completionKey
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.initIDs(Native Method)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsLinkSupport.getRealPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.toRealPath(Unknown Source)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar(Unknown Source)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.text.DateFormat.get(Unknown Source)
at java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.tools.i18n.LocalizedResource.init(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.tools.i18n.LocalizedResource.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.init(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: looks like a bug for oracle... have you recently upgraded/updated your version of java? installed any windows patches/security fixes?

Comment: Maybe yes. I always updates my Eclipse when it asks me about it.

Comment: try running this with another java version

Comment: looks like youre running entirely within eclipse. either install an older version of eclipse (alongside the current) or figure out how to make it use another jdk. im not an eclipse user, so my knowledge of it is limited.

Comment: meanwhile, looks like its an issue with java8? - http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CzlbZmKJLjkJ:https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036134+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk

Answer (score 0):

This is an Error (!) that is due to running code that was compiled against a class with a field and executing it with another (compiled) version without that field.

Go back and check installed versions, recompile everything, etc. etc-

Comment: What do you mean saying 'go back'? getting back previous version of jdk?

Comment: No, I don't think it's a JDK version problem, unless you did switch back and forth. It could be a Derby jar, or whatever else you import. - Above all, recompile/rebuild everything.

Comment: Of course, make sure that javac and java are called from the same Java version.

Comment: I rebuilt my project and saw no changes.. I also considered I can't start my tomcat server. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException occured

Comment: This means: Reflection code calls a method (or constructor) and this throws an error. Is this in any way related to that other Error? -- Something has changed in your setup.

Comment: I created web project hour ago. I just added derby nature and attempted to start it. What could have changed there?